# Странный текст в Vim help файлах

Tags: vim

Обнаружил такой текст во многих местах своего Vim help. Что это и зачем?
`vim:tw=78:fo=tcq2:isk=!-~,^*,^\|,^\":ts=8:ft=help:norl:`
Google не дал ничего - только бессвязные куски исходников.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ["modeline"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#modeline). Если такой текст находится в последних или первых двух строках файла, Vim читает настройки оттуда и применяет к текущему буферу.

Пример: Принудительная интерпретация файла `.rdf`, как `xml`:

```
<!--
vim: ft=xml
-->
<!-- rest of file -->
```